# Recursive and numerical methods in python, incorrect list value attribution

Tags: python, list, recursion, iteration

I am currently implementing a SOR(Successive Over Relaxation) and Gauss-Seidel method for a python project, the iterative process (all the calculations) in itself is working as expected when I call the function outside of `main()`, however, since the process is recursive and depends on two lists that change values every iteration, I believe the lists are not receiving their correct values accordingly, since python ends up printing the wrong answer. This is what I currently have for my `main()`:

```
.
.
.
om=1
while om<2:
    k=0
    X=ite_SOR(X, Xp, om, i)[0]
    Xp=ite_SOR(X, Xp, om, i)[1]
    error=max(abs(abs(np.array(X)-abs(np.array(Xp)))))
    while error>1e-6:
        X=Xp[:]
        Xp=ite_SOR(X, Xp, om, i)[1]
        k+=1
    om+=0.2
```

The `ite_SOR` function is given as follows (I omitted the bulk of the function that I believe was not causing the problem since it is composed only of some weird calculations) :

```
def ite_SOR(X, Xp, om, n):
    for i in range(len(X)):
        
        ...

        Xp[i]=(1-om)*X[i]+om*(b + d + e + c)
    return X, Xp
```

This function takes both lists `X` and `Xp` and changes the list `Xp` in function of `X`. Returning the initial value of `X` and the new value of `Xp` (note that at the start of the process both lists are the same)

In the `main()` function both lists, `X`, and `Xp` end up being the same, which is not what I want. What needs to happen is `X` to receive the new value of `Xp` and run through `ite_SOR(X, Xp, om, n)` again and again until the error is smaller than `1e-6`.

I have tried to print the values of `X` and `Xp` for every iteration, but both are always the same and never end up changing, up to a point where python only prints lists that contain `nan`, which I don't even know the meaning of.

Any help is greatly appreciated, if any more information is needed about my code, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Are `X` and `Xp` references to the same list? If so, modifying one of them modifies the other. You need to make a copy, it doesn't happen automatically when you assign.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `X` and `Xp` are being confused. In Python, it doesn't create a new object but rather creates a new reference to the existing object.

When you do `X=Xp[:]` in your while loop, you're creating a new list with same element as `Xp`

You can use `copy()`

```
om=1
while om<2:
    k=0
    X, Xp = ite_SOR(X.copy(), Xp.copy(), om, i)
    error=max(abs(abs(np.array(X)-abs(np.array(Xp)))))
    while error>1e-6:
        X=Xp.copy()
        _, Xp = ite_SOR(X.copy(), Xp.copy(), om, i)
        k+=1
    om+=0.2
```

`copy()` function is used to ensure that `ite_SOR()` is working with a new list, not a reference to the existing list.